# Angular5 No response with Routerlink and button in IE and firefox

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, firefox, angular-cli, shim

I have a new Angular 5 CLI app and have built a navmenu component for the top section of the app.  When I click my menu items in Edge and Chrome it works perfectly and follows my route as defined in app.module.ts.  However when i click the link in IE11 or Firefox nothing happens.  I went and enabled all the polyfills I could see listed in polyfills.ts but still no change, although they did fix a problem with rendering the material icons in IE11.

```
    <span *ngIf="isLoggedIn() == false">
      <button  [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']" mat-icon-button >
        <a [routerLink]="['/login']">
          <mat-icon>account_circle</mat-icon> Login
        </a>

      </button>
    <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    </span>
```

If i take the

```
     <a [routerLink]="['/login']">
          <mat-icon>account_circle</mat-icon> Login
        </a>
```

part out of the button node I can click it and it routes correctly in IE11 and Firefox, so my route is fine.  Somehow activating the anchor  is not working in IE11 and Firefox.  Does anyone have an idea what this could be?  Edge and Chrome work perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to this is actually quite simple.

The <button> tags are actually not needed and the mat-icon-button styling can be applied to the <a> tag

```
    <a [routerLink]="['/login']" [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']" mat-icon-button>
      <mat-icon>account_circle</mat-icon> Login
    </a>
```

That achieves the desired result.  What I found was that the button was obscuring the anchor in IE and firefox.  When I put a test

```
onclick="this.children[0].children[0].click()"
```

on the button the route worked in Firefox and IE which led me to the answer that the message was not getting though to the anchor on those two browsers.